# Trying to add 2 files to seperate lists to read from, I need to combine both into one list

Tags: c#

Purpose:    This app. reads the girls names from the GirlNames.txt file & boy names from the BoyNames.txt file. 
This app puts these names into separate arrays & when the user enters a name of a boy &/or a girl, the app displays a message indicating whether the name(s) were among the most popular names from 2000-2009.

```
    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Opens BoyNames.txt & writes to list.
            StreamReader boys;
            string boyNames;
            boys = File.OpenText("BoyNames.txt");
            List<string> boyNameList = new List<string>();

            //Opens GirlNames.txt & writes to list.
            StreamReader girls;
            string girlNames;
            girls = File.OpenText("GirlNames.txt");
            List<string> girlNameList = new List<string>();

            // Get user input.
            boyNames = boyNameTextBox.Text;
            girlNames = girlNameTextBox.Text;

            //Read Boys names
            while (!boys.EndOfStream)
            {
                boyNameList.Add(boys.ReadLine());

            } // end While loop.

            //Read girls names
            while (!girls.EndOfStream)
            {
                girlNameList.Add(girls.ReadLine());

            } // end While loop.

            int boysPosition = boyNameList.IndexOf(boyNames);
            int girlsPosition = girlNameList.IndexOf(girlNames);

            if (boysPosition != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The boy name you entered is one of the most popular names.");

            } // end boys position IF loop.

            if (girlsPosition != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The girl name you entered is one of the most popular names.");

            } // end girlsPosition IF loop

            if (boysPosition != -1 && girlsPosition != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The name you entered was found on both the boys and girls name lists!");
            }

            else if (boysPosition == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The boy name you have entered is NOT one of the most popular names.");

            } // end Else If.

            else if ( girlsPosition == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The girl name you have entered is NOT one of the most popular names.");

            } // end Else If.

        } // end try block.
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display and error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        } // end catch block.

    } // end searchButton.
```

Comment: What's the particular problem you're having?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: When I run this on Visual Studio, it tells me it cannot find the file. I updated the code from with some minor changes I had originally.

Comment: I commented out the try/catch block, then ran the program and this is the error it gives: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file.  It is happening on the line that reads: boys = File.OpenText("BoyNames.txt");   I don't understand why I'm getting this. I'm new to programming & this is how it is shown in the book. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds the files are not in the working directory (where the exe file is in). Try to specify the complete path like:  `File.OpenText(@"C:\MyApp\SomeFolder\BoyNames.txt");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `combinedList` at all.  This is just a waste of memory and CPU time making extra copies of the lists.

Below uses LINQ to search both lists:

```
string nameToSearch = "Some Name";
//if match is true, it exists in one of the lists
bool match = boyNameList.Any(x => x == nameToSearch) || girlNameList.Any(x => x == nameToSearch);
```

Other things to consider are using `ReadAllLines` and exactly how you want to define a match between two strings.  The above code doesn't address things like white space, culture, partial match, etc..

I'd look at the documentation [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings?view=netframework-4.8) as a good start for string comparison.  There's more to it than meets the eye at first glance.

Comment: I had to add the name .txt files into the \bin\debug folder for Visual Studio. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

**Improvements**

Use built-in function like **ReadAllLines** or **ReadAllText** to make the reading operation more safe.

If the list of names, in the test file, are arranged as follows

***.txt**

```
Name Surmane
Name Surmane
...
```

Use the following code to read the content

```
string[] names = File.ReadAllLines(@"BoyNames.txt");
```

If there are a separator and all names are on the same line use

```
string namesString = File.ReadAllLines(@"BoyNames.txt");
string[] names = namesString .Split(',');
```

**Procedure**

The following code search for a name key culture-insensitive.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string test = "kenoby";

            List<string> boyNameList = new List<string>() {"Luke Skywalker", "Han Solo", "Obi Wan Kenoby"};
            List<string> girlNameList = new List<string>() { "Leila Skywalker" };

            List<string> combinedList = new List<string>();
            combinedList.AddRange(boyNameList);
            combinedList.AddRange(girlNameList);

            int results = combinedList.Where(n => n.Contains(test, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count();
            if (results > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The name you entered is among the most popular names.");
            } 
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The name you have entered is not among the most popular names.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
The name you entered is among the most popular names.
```

Comment: I had to add the name .txt files into the \bin\debug folder for Visual Studio. Thank you!!